# Can i write my own UI and backend functionality code in frappe ERPnext app?

Tags: javascript, python, erp, erpnext, frappe

i'm new to frappe ERPnext tool, i just go through all type of modules and doctypes in frappe, it's automatically generate the code inside of our app folder as well database, as per our custom doctypes and module setup, in some cases my client's businness logic is can't build with frappe tools and keys, can i write my own UI and backend logics directly inside of installed frappe framework folder,

is that possible to achieve this with frappe ERPnext app,

please give a tips regarding my question, it will really lead to me to initiate a project on frappe ERPnext.

Thanks in advance.

i watch a frappe youtube tutorial, there were only configuring and customising the modules from frappe editable tools,

Comment: You cannot write your login in frappe/erpnext app. Instead you can create a custom app to write your logic.

Comment: ok @ShridharPatil Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Check Pages and POSAwesome.